# uisearchbar crashes after pressing cancel

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, nsarray, uisearchbar

My filteredContentForSearchText ignores predicate after user presses cancel on search bar in iOS.

I am filtering an array with a uisearchbar with the following method:

```
#pragma mark Content Filtering
-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope {


    [self.filteredUsersArray removeAllObjects];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.fullName contains[c] %@",searchText];
    self.filteredUsersArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.usersArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];

    if ([self.filteredUsersArray count] > 0) { 

    }else{
        User *tempUser = self.addedUsersArray[0];
        tempUser.fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Search for '%@'", searchText];

        [self.filteredUsersArray addObject:tempUser];

    }
}
```

Everything works perfect until a user presses cancel or clears there search.  After that action occurs this line no longer matches and populates the array:

```
self.filteredUsersArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.usersArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
```

Does anyone know why the array would return a count of zero after cancel is pressed even when the criteria matches?

Comment: is this an iOS bug???

Comment: Can you show us the crash you get?